# ActiveRecord: how to find constraints?

Tags: nhibernate, constraints, castle-activerecord

I'm kind of new to ActiveRecord (using CastleProject) and gaining knowledge step by step. 
Now I'm running into another situation.

I've got a `Media` class that is used in some other classes: `Content`, `Case` and `Service`. Now when I want to delete a `Media` class, I want to check if there are any constraints with the previous named classes. Is there a best-practice on how to achieve this? Or are there any functions within the `CastleProject`/`Nhibernate` which might help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to catch the database exception when violating a constraint, check out [ISQLExceptionConverter](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2009/06/improving-ado-exception-management-in.html).

But if you want to find out exactly what records in other tables will trigger the constraint exception you'll have to run whatever queries are needed yourself.